# Is $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z^2=(x^2 +y^2)^2 \}$ a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The set in the title can be rewritten as $f^{-1}(0)$, where $f(x,y,z) = z^2 - (x^2 + y^2)^2$, and 0 is not a regular value, so I can't use the implicit function theorem. What techniques can I employ to endow this set with a differential structure? Is it immersed (or embedded) in euclidean space? I would say it isn't embedded, because it is two ellyptic paraboloids, symmetric in relation to the xy plane and intersecting at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title:

Intuitively, if it is a manifold, it has to be a surface, so locally diffeomorphic to the Euclidean plane. But a neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$ in your set looks like two neighborhoods of the origin $(0,0)$ glued together at the origin.

This is clearly topologically different from a neighborhood of the origin in the Euclidean plane. So it is not a manifold.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the square root, you have that $z = \pm (x^2 + y^2)$, and you can sketch both of these surfaces simultaneously.  It's not that different from the curve $y^2 = x^4$, where you have $y = \pm x^2$.  In both cases, you have a local cut point.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in my question. I just don't know if because of this, I can conclude that it is a manifold.

Comment: I added that you can therefore find a local cut point.  A 2-dimensional manifold cannot have a local cut point since removing one point does not disconnect a disk.